# Cannot run PyQt program on another computer

Tags: pyqt5

I started working on a Python 3.9 QT5 program about a year ago on Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal) and then let it slide. Today I tried to work with it on another computer, which runs Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish) and there seems to be an issue with PyQt somehow.

```sh
python src/main.py
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/mslinn/venv/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted
```

I tried `pip install PyQt5` but that made no difference. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Uninstall all the pip-installed stuff and install the official ubuntu packages instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following resolved the problem. There was need to diddle with any pip-related stuff:

```sh
$ sudo apt install qt5dxcb-plugin
```